# Markov Chain Probability question

Tags: matrices

Im having trouble with this markov probability question as my textbook doesnt really have an example to go off on.

**Question**

[image]

**Working** (2 answers i figured may be right/wrong)

[image]

i feel like i should be using the stationary vector but i dont particularly understand why i would.

Answer (score 0):

You found the transition matrix and its $4$th degree correctly:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}0.7&0.3\\ 0.5&0.5\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow M^4=\begin{pmatrix}0.6256&0.3744\\ 0.6240&0.3760\end{pmatrix}$$
However, the initial state vector must be $X_0=(1,0)$ (not $X_0=(0.5,0.5)$), because it is stated "if it is sunny on Sunday", implying its probability is $1$. Hence:
$$X_1=X_0M=\begin{pmatrix}0.7&0.3\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{(which complies with the conditions)}\\
X_4=X_0M^4=\begin{pmatrix}0.6256&0.3744\end{pmatrix},$$ 
which implies that the probability of rain on Thursday, on the fourth day after Sunday (which is the state $X_4$) is $0.3744$.